# Run a file multiple times with different parameters

Tags: exe

I am working in Windows and at my work i have a VB program that i need to run multiple times. It takes two input files. One of them is constant and the other input file changes according to which a new output file is created every time the program is run. 
I need to know how can i automate this. Can this be done using a batch file? I an not sure if the VB program takes cmd inputs. How can I check and what shall I read? I don't have access to its source.

Every program that runs runs in the shell. right? So where can I see that? Maybe I could manipulate and repeat the exe execution using different parameters.

Comment: How are you running the vb program right now? How do you specify the input and output file (as your question says) now?

Comment: there is a browse button each to add both files then a browse button to save the output.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write a GUI Automation script. Following Stack exchange threads can help you get started with it:

1. [Automate GUI tasks](https://superuser.com/questions/29254/automate-gui-tasks)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120359/tools-for-automated-gui-testing-on-windows

Comment: Thanks the tools are not perfect but they really helped

Comment: You are welcome, you can thank me by voting for the answer ;):)